# How to access variable to the root file?

Tags: sass

I have three scss files and I'm trying to access a color variable. First file name is `color.scss`, it stays in `theme` folder, the second file is `index.scss` that also stays in `theme` folder. I used `@forward` for `color.scss` file, and in root folder `style.scss` file uses `@use` to call `index.scss`. Now when trying to access variable from `index.scss` file its showing an error.

**color.scss** (theme folder)

```
$color: #f90
```

**index.scss** (theme folder)

```
@forward 'color' as theme1-\*;
```

**style.scss** (root)

```
@use "themes";

p {
  color:color.theme-$color; // here its showing error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're encountering an error because you're not accessing the variable correctly. When using @forward with a namespace in Sass, you need to refer to the variable with the namespace. So, in your style.scss, you should access the $color variable as follows:

```
@use "themes";

p {
  color: themes.theme1-color; // <== use the namespace here
}
```

Also, make sure you've correctly set up the file paths and don't forget to end your color declaration in color.scss with a semicolon (;).

Hope this helps!